# How do I process an XML string with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, ajax

I am really struggling with a Jquery script I can't get to work.

I have an XML string and I want to return the name 'Miki' from it, however its just not working and i can't figure it out. Can someone help me?

```
function LoadParseXML() {

         var xml
         xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><CATALOG><VAR><PREVIOUSPAT>Miki</PREVIOUSPAT></VAR></CATALOG>';
         loadXMLDoc(xml, 'PREVIOUSPAT');
          }


     function loadXMLDoc(url, Node) {
         var xmlhttp;
         var txt, x, xx, i;
         if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
             xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
         }
         else {// code for IE6, IE5
             xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
         }
         xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
             if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {

                 x = xmlhttp.responseXML.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("VAR");

                 for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {

                     xx = x[i].getElementsByTagName(Node);

                     txt = xx[0].firstChild.nodeValue;

                     alert(txt);

                 }

             }
         }

         xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
         xmlhttp.send();
     }
```

Comment: log `xx` variable and see what's inside

Comment: Just skimming over your code, why aren't you using jQuery when you mention it? jQuery has `$.ajax()` and `$.parseXML()` which should hopefully fix any problems you're having. For traversal through the XML document, use jQuery methods like `.find()`, `.filter()`, or `.children()`. And then `.text()` to retrieve element content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this jQuery code to loop PREVIOUSPAT occurrences

```
var xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><CATALOG><VAR><PREVIOUSPAT>Miki</PREVIOUSPAT></VAR></CATALOG>';
xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml );
$xml = $( xmlDoc );

$xml.find('CATALOG > VAR > PREVIOUSPAT').each(function(){
    alert( $(this).text() );
})
```

Comment: God bless you all, thank you Michael B, I didn't realise it was that straight forward. I need to obviously learn more about JQuery but you good samaritans helped me out considerably. Thank you Ian too!